# name not defined error in forloop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am getting name not defined in python block , though i have defined it correctly

what I tried:

```
accounts = ['abcd','abcde']
    for account in accounts:
        print(account)
        new_col = 0
        terminated_col = 0
        
        try:
            ak = jout['data']['client_id']
            sk = jout['data']['client_secret']
            credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(tenant=tenant_var, client_id=ak, secret=sk)
            subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credential)
            subscription = next(subscription_client.subscriptions.list())
            resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription.subscription_id)
            time.sleep(10)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)  
                
          
        for rg in resource_client.resource_groups.list():    
            try:
               print(rg.name) 
               
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

getting error like:

```
    for rg in resource_client.resource_groups.list():
NameError: name 'resource_client' is not defined
```

actually checking these for all accounts in list, so ideally above is correct ?  can someone suggest

Comment: Looks like the try/catch block is failing somewhere and therefore "resource_client" is never declared nor assigned. Try removing the try catch to see the actual error message you are interested in.

Comment: i removed try and declared these resource client even before for loop, then i get '   raise StopIteration("End of paging")
StopIteration: End of paging`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that error happened BEFORE you defined it. I'd recommend defining it in both the try and except statements. Basically:

```
except Exception as e:
       resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscription.subscription_id)
       print(e)
```

Answer (score -2):

`resource_client` is only available in the scope of the `try`. Just before the try, add a `resource_client = None` to declare it.

Comment: [nope](https://repl.it/repls/MountainousSmallKeygens#main.py)

Comment: if i declare bfore catch. it says `for rg in resource_client.resource_groups.list():`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'resource_groups'`

Comment: Can you check the documentation of `ResourceManagementClient` and search for the return value when something fails ?

Comment: when i remove try catch..i get this error     raise StopIteration("End of paging")
StopIteration: End of paging

Comment: Even if you have an Error, you continue to execute the script, and you try to do something with `resource_client`, that may not have been initialized. Put the second for loop in the try too, or test the value of `resource_client` for `None` (with the initialization I said earlier) before going in this loop